# How to call function from another component to another component

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

Now I'm confused how to fire function from component to control something in another component. Can anyone help me on this?

```
Structure:
App.svelte
L checklist.svelte
  L button <-- this button want to call function in stage component
L stage.svelte
```

```
checklist.svelte:
<button on:click="handleMove" />
```

```
stage.svelte:
export function fly(x, y) {
   $map.flyto(x, y);
}
```

I have a button in checklist component that want to activate function that in stage component.

Stage component is a map that have x y position and function that move things inside this component.

How can I call function in stage component from the outside (checklist components)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Patterns like these may indicate a code smell. Something that is inefficiently structured. Something that doesn't have a clear separation of concern and responsibility.

Comment: To be more specific. in stage.svelte it use leaflet map. Some function it provided by the itself. That means if I want to control things in that component. I have to make it communicate from outside. And I don't know how make it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Dispatch a custom `checklist-click` event from Checklist.
2. In App, listen to this click event and call `fly` on Stage.

```svelte
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import Checklist from './Checklist.svelte';
    import Stage from './Stage.svelte';
    
    let stage;
    
    function handleClick({ detail }) {
        // these come from the second argument to dispatch in Checklist.svelte
        const { x, y } = detail;
        stage.fly(x, y);
    }
</script>

<h1>App</h1>

<!-- Listen to the event fired with dispatch('checklist-click') -->
<Checklist on:checklist-click={handleClick}></Checklist>

<!-- Store a reference to this component instance so that we can call `fly` on it -->
<Stage bind:this={stage}></Stage>

<!-- Checklist.svelte -->
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    function handleMove() {
        dispatch('checklist-click', {x: 5, y: 10});
    }
</script>

<h2>Checklist</h2>

<button on:click={handleMove}>
    Move
</button>

<!-- Stage.svelte -->
<script>
    export function fly(x, y) {
        console.log(`fly called from stage with x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
    }
</script>


<h2>Stage</h2>
```

For more on dispatching component events, see the [Svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events).

Comment: I read about this dispatcher and I did it inside component. Never thought about to use on parent and fire dispatch from the inside to outside. Your solution helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

first and the most flexible one is to create a writable `store` to use it anywhere

second it to use `context`

third is to declare it in `App.svelte` and `bind` it to both children

Comment: Store is quite useful. Maybe if I have more experience. I'll refactor and try your solution. Thank you.